# Instantiating a default instance for an Enthought trait

Tags: python, enthought, traits

Consider this simple minimal example:

```
from traits.api import Instance, Str, HasTraits

class Person(HasTraits):
    name = Str("hooked")

class Chair(HasTraits):
    sitting = Instance(Person)

t = Chair()
print t.sitting.name
```

This fails since `t.sitting` evaluates to `None`. [Enthought's traits module](http://docs.enthought.com/traits/traits_api_reference/traits.html) will enforce that the type of `t.sitting` is a `Person` but how can I get the default person to instantiate here? I don't want to pass any parameters to the `Chair(**kwargs)` I'd like this to be done automatically. The expected output to the print statement is `hooked`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is interesting. According to the Instance docstring, calling Instance will return None if klass is a class and arg and kw are not specified. arg and kw have default values of None and so calling Instance(Person) is returning None like you are seeing. 
I got your code to work by adding "kw = {}" or "args = []" to the Instance call.

```
from traits.api import Instance, Str, HasTraits

class Person(HasTraits):
    name = Str("hooked")

class Chair(HasTraits):
    sitting = Instance(Person, kw = {})

t = Chair()
print t.sitting.name
```

This prints "hooked" as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that seems to solve the problem on my end. I've edited your post, I think you messed up some of the code formatting. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 3):

You've explicitly defined `Chair` so that its default instance does not instantiate its attribute `sitting`, and that's what is happening. If you'd rather instantiate `sitting` by default, then you can.

So take your pick. If you want to keep your original definition of Chair, but *this time* ensure that sitting is instantiated to its default, then:

```
from traits.api import Instance, Str, HasTraits

class Person(HasTraits):
    name = Str("hooked")

class Chair(HasTraits):
    sitting = Instance(Person)

t = Chair(sitting=Person())
print t.sitting.name
```

But if you'd rather that a default Chair always be instantiated with a default `sitting`, then (EDIT: and showing traitsui in action):

```
from traits.api import Instance, Str, HasTraits
from traitsui.api import Item, View

class Person(HasTraits):
    name = Str("hooked")

class Chair(HasTraits):
    sitting = Instance(Person,())
    view = View((Item( 'sitting', style = 'custom')))

t = Chair()
print t.sitting.name
t.configure_traits()

# or overridden by:
w = Chair(sitting=Person(name='snooked'))
print w.sitting.name
```

Comment: Ohhhh! I didn't realize that `Person` defined a trait too (though I guess now it's obvious). I thought all non-base types had to be wrapped in an `Instance`. I guess I don't understand the purpose of an `Instance` then. I'm happy to see there is a strong Enthought community here on SO, you guys have been helpful!

Comment: "purpose of `Instance`": (a) it's common to want to type such an attribute without the class knowing anything about the actual identity of its value. (b) Also, if you want to use traitsui to display / edit the object, I think you need to specify Instance explicitly. Therefore I'm revising my 2nd case to show this in action (the resulting Instance code is now closer to jcorson's)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is to create a method in your Chair class that instantiates a default instance of your Person class. This method name takes the form of '_name_default' where name is your trait attribute. This method is called when Chair is instantiated. For reference see [this page](https://docs.enthought.com/traits/traits_user_manual/advanced.html?highlight=_default#name_default) in the Traits documentation.

See the code example below which I have tested in v5.1.2 and v6.2.0.

```
from traits.api import Instance, Str, HasTraits

class Person(HasTraits):
    name = Str("hooked")

class Chair(HasTraits):
   sitting = Instance(Person)

def _sitting_default(self):
    #Instantiate your class here
    return Person()

t = Chair()
print(t.sitting.name)
```